# Haskell exporting large number of functions

Tags: haskell, module, export

I am writing a module which has rather large number of functions that need to be exported. Also this module has a large number of data constructions.

Suppose my module contains the following:

```
module MyUtils (A(..), B(..),C(..),D(..),f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6) where
--Data constructors
data A = ...
data B = ...
data C = ...
data D = ...
--functions
f1 :: A -> B
f2 :: A -> B -> C
f3 :: A -> B -> D
f4 :: A -> B -> A
f5 :: A -> B -> B
f6 :: A -> B
```

I saw the Data.Map source [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/src/Data-Map.html)
It shows it is exporting a large number of functions in a very big list.

But If I want to export everything, can it be done with a yet shortcut method, something like,

```
module MyUtils (..) where
```

?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, just leave out the `(..)` entirely. By default, all names are exported.

```
module MyUtiles where
...
```

If there are a *large* number of functions you want to export alongside a *small* number of functions you want to hide, it's best to put the hidden ones in another module and import it.

Answer (score 7):

You can also also do it the following way:

```
module MyUtiles (module MyUtiles) where
```

It is sometimes desirable (or required) to use an export list. For example if you want to export everything in the current module and re-export bindings from another module.

Comment: I found this helpful. Thanks! It got rid of a [-Wmissing-export-lists] ghc warning for me, and I did not have to write an absurd number of lines of code, nor suppress the warning.